# Python Pandas Hierarchical index iterrows without converting data types

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a hierarchical index.

```
In [57]: df = pd.DataFrame({('potential', 'sum'): {0: 8.0498308000000005, 1: 10901.381148799968}, ('datapoint_num', 'min'): {0: 1, 1: 6}, ('step_index', 'si'): {0: 1, 1: 6}, ('datapoint_num', 'N'): {0: 5, 1: 8600}, ('potential', 'sum_of_squares'): {0: 12.959955292916959, 1: 13910.219889184529}, ('datapoint_num', 'max'): {0: 5, 1: 8605}})

In [58]: df
Out[58]: 
   datapoint_num                potential                  step_index
               N   max  min           sum  sum_of_squares          si
0              5     5    1      8.049831       12.959955           1
1           8600  8605    6  10901.381149    13910.219889           6
```

That I'm using to calculate a bunch of summary statistics off of streaming data. I'd like to iterate over its rows, without changing the data types. Its initial data types are:

```
In [43]: df.dtypes
step_index       si                  int64
datapoint_num    max                 int64
                 N                   int64
                 min                 int64
potential        sum_of_squares    float64
                 sum               float64
sn                                   int64
```

If I call

```
for sn, row in df.iterrows:
    row.dtype
```

I see that pandas converts to a series and everything becomes a float64. dif.iloc[0] also seems to preform the same type conversion.

Using

```
for i in df.index:
    row = df[df.sn == i]
    row.dtypes
```

I still have a dataframe and it seems to work just fine (assuming my index is unique), but I assume that is much more inefficient.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do with each row?  You can use `itertuples`, for instance, which will give you a tuple of individual values.

Comment: I'm passing the parameters to a bunch of different functions to calculate more advanced statistics (the dataframe has a lot more rows then what I showed). itertuples is a good option, but then you loose your indexes. I might take the speed hit, so that I can keep the code maintainable.

Comment: Can you please use df.to_dict() to make your sample data easier to import.

Answer (score 0):

You can use namedtuples and dictionary comprehension assignment:

```
Row = namedtuple('Row', ['N', 'max', 'min', 'sum', 'sum_of_squares', 'si'])

rows = {i: Row(*df.iloc[i, :]) for i in df.index}

>>> rows
{0: Row(N=5.0, max=5.0, min=1.0, sum=8.0498308000000005, sum_of_squares=12.959955292916959, si=1.0),
 1: Row(N=8600.0, max=8605.0, min=6.0, sum=10901.381148799968, sum_of_squares=13910.219889184529, si=6.0)}

>>> type(rows[0].min)
numpy.float64
```

I noticed that the imported data types are also not what you'd expect, so I'm not sure how this will work for your needs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('potential', 'sum'): {0: 8.0498308000000005, 1: 10901.381148799968}, ('datapoint_num', 'min'): {0: 1, 1: 6}, ('step_index', 'si'): {0: 1, 1: 6}, ('datapoint_num', 'N'): {0: 5, 1: 8600}, ('potential', 'sum_of_squares'): {0: 12.959955292916959, 1: 13910.219889184529}, ('datapoint_num', 'max'): {0: 5, 1: 8605}})

>>> df.iloc[0, 2]
1.0

>>> type(df.iloc[0, 2])
numpy.float64
```

You are probably expecting an int64.

Also, because this appears to be for a specific need, it should work because the sub levels are unique (e.g. there is only on 'max').  More generally, one could create chained keys via level0:_level1 (e.g. potential:_sum_of_squares).

As these rows are now tuples, the data cannot be changed (which is probably what you want).